# How to print page-wise totals at the end of every page using table

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, report, reporting, rdlc

I'm trying make a report which contains some prices on every row, and I want to print the sum of prices -which are printed on the page- at the bottom of every page. I don't find it smart to print the grand totals in every page, for my situation at least.

Example:

First Page

```
Name            | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 | Price4   -table header

Record 1        |   10   |   15   |   15   |   20

Record 2        |   15   |   15   |   15   |   15

Total 2 records |   25   |   30   |   30   |   35     -table footer for page 1
```

---

Second Page

```
Name             | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 | Price4  -starting 2. page, table header

Record 3         |   20   |   30   |   30   |   30

Total 1 records  |   20   |   30   |   30   |   30    -end of the table

Grand T. (3 rec) |   45   |   60   |   60   |   65    -end of the table
```

I put 2 records for the first page and 1 for second page, its just to demonstrate what I want. I did my best to make it look clear.

Comment: Are a predictable number of price rows printed per page, or can it vary?

Comment: @AnnL.I don't enable the auto grow property, so all pages should contain a fixed nubmer of rows, but the last page.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible ways this could be done.

Since you say that there's a predictable number of rows per page (let's say, for ease of constructing an example, that there are 25), you could do the following:

In your query, assign each row a consecutive sequence number.  You could do this like this:

```
WITH Cte
AS (
    SELECT Name,
           Price1,
           Price2,
           Price3,
           Price4,
           RecordNumber = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [whatever])
    FROM   [tables]
)
SELECT    Name,
          Price1,
          [etc]
          RowGroup = Floor((RecordNumber * 1.0) / 25 )
FROM      Cte
ORDER BY  RecordNumber
```

Then, in your report, group by `RowGroup`, and subtotal your rows.

If you have other, higher-level groupings in the report, you will probably have to start a new page after each higher-level group, because otherwise it will throw the placement off for the page subtotals.

(You might also be able to do this with the RowNumber() function in SSRS without modifying the underlying query, but there are a lot of rules about what functions you can use when, and I don't know if that would be allowed.)

The other option I can think of is more complicated and involves using the report Code section and setting some module-level functions.  Let me know if you think that's something you need to see.

Comment: Thank you, this is an acceptable answer, btw, you might want to swap `RecordNumber as ...` into `... as RecordNumber`, just a small syntax error, but the way is smart. If you mean something different than the Code section in report properties by `report code-behind`, yes I would like to see about them.

Comment: @SmT  Thanks for the correction!  Yes, I did mean the Code section when I said "report code-behind".